# how do you change the rank of tensorflow object

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hello I am new in tensorflow I make my graph and I try to run it but I get this error :

```
ValueError: Shape (3,) must have rank 2
```

which comes from this line

```
tf.matmul(tf.matmul(phix, tf.transpose(param)), B)
```

I checked the rank of my variable phix and the result is `0`, I didn't understand why because its shape is `(3,3)`. this is my script, could you help me please.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def phi(x, b, w, B):
    z = tf.matmul(x,w)
    phix = tf.cos(z) + b #  attention shapes
    phix /= tf.sqrt(float(float(int(w.get_shape()[0])) / 2.))

    return phix, B



def model(phix, B, param) :
    return tf.matmul(tf.matmul(phix, tf.transpose(param)), B)

B = tf.constant(1., shape=[1])  # constant (non trainable)
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,1])  # variable
W2 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.random_normal(shape=[1, 3]),trainable=False ,name="W2")
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[3]),trainable=False , name="b2")
y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[3,3]),trainable=False )
param = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[3]))  # variable trainable
norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(param)))**2 ## attention ici c'est par ce que param est un vecteur de une dimmention 
phix, B = phi (x2,b2,W2,B)
lamda = tf.constant(1. , shape=[3])
cost = tf.nn.l2_loss(y - model(phix, B, param)) + lamda *  norm

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i  in range(10):
        sess.run(opt)
        z4_op = sess.run(opt , feed_dict = {x2: [[1.0],[2.0],[3.0]]})

    print(z4_op)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matmul), the inputs have to be 2D matrices (otherwise, you can use [tf.mul](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul) or reshape the tensors to be 2D). The reshaping would look like this:

```
def model(phix, B, param):
    one = tf.reshape(tf.matmul(phix, tf.reshape(param, [3, 1])), [3, 1])
    return tf.matmul(one, tf.reshape(B, [1,1]))
```

You also need to feed the value of the `x2` placeholder every time you execute op that depends on it:

```
for i  in range(10):
    sess.run(opt, feed_dict = {x2: [[1.0],[2.0],[3.0]]})
    z4_op = sess.run(opt, feed_dict = {x2: [[1.0],[2.0],[3.0]]})
```